# can't add route in Slim

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, slim, front-controller

My problem is I can't add a route other than `'/'`.
if I change `/` to `/hello` I get a 404 error.  I think I have a mistake in my paths or `.htaccess`.

my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] –
```

here is my code and my project structure

```
require '../../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello', function () {   //'/' works fine
    echo "Hello";
});
$app->run();
```

[image]

Comment: Are you going to the right URL? So `localhost/hello` ? Your code is fine. Ofcourse will the `/` respond with a `404` because you have changed it to `/hello`

Comment: I go to  : http://localhost/API/v1/DEVOLO_UI/form/hello

Comment: To which folder is your documentroot pointed? I guess you need to use `localhost/DEVOLO_UI/hello` and what shows your developer tools(network tab)?

Comment: the vendor folder is in localhost/API/v1 but my index.php is in localhost/API/v1/DEVOLO_UI/form

Comment: What does yout htaccess say? Looks like there is the problem. Your htacces has to forward all requests to that index.php.

Comment: Btw / works because you are requesting index.php - /hello requests file/folder named hello.

Comment: @bourax Can you add the content of your .htaccess to your question please? And can you try to move your `index.php` file to `v1` directory?

Answer (score 1):

In your `.htaccess` file you have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] –
```

Since you're not specifying a path for `index.php`, Apache will try to load an `index.php` file in the current directory. But since that file is not there you'll get a response with error 404.

But since the `.htaccess` file is not under the directory you are accessing, it's not even loaded by the server. You need to do one of the following:

1. Move `index.php` file to project root dir, as people suggested in the comments on your question (which is the best solution).
2. Move `.htaccess` to the same directory as `index.php` (it seems to be `DEVOLO_UI/form`).

By the way, have you considered use only Composer's autoload? You don't need to call both autoloads: Slim's and Composer's. In your `index.php` you may write something like this:

```
// Set the current dir to application's root.
// You may have to change the path depending on 
// where you'll keep your index.php.
$path = realpath('../../');
chdir($path);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// Your routes followed by $app->run();
// ...
```